# How can an executable be this small in file size?

Tags: windows, portable-executable, malware

I've been generating payloads on Metasploit and I've been experimenting with the different templates and one of the templates you can have your payload as is `exe-small`. The type of payload I've been generating is a windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp and just using the normal `exe` template it has a file size around 72 KB however `exe-small` outputs a payload the size of 2.4kb. Why is this? And how could I apply this to my programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest possible [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) file is just 97 bytes - and it does nothing (just return).

The smallest runnable executable today is 133 bytes, because Windows requires `kernel32` being loaded. Executing a PE file with no imports is not possible.

At that size it can already download payload from the Internet by specifying an UNC path in the import table.

To achieve such a small executable, you have to

- implement in assembler, mainly to get rid of the C runtime
- decrease the file alignment which is 1024 by default
- remove the DOS stub that prints the message "This program cannot be run in DOS mode"
- Merge some of the PE parts into the MZ header
- Remove the data directory

The full description is available in a larger research [blog post called TinyPE](http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/).

Comment: I disagree. Read my initial reply. I have a 20-byte valid .com file I've been using on MS-DOS times.

Comment: @Overmind: a COM file is not a PE file, so there's no discrepancy. Does that file still run on nowadays Windows (7 or later)? COM files have no header, no metadata etc. Also note: this question was migrated from Security.SE in the context of Metasploit, where I assumed that someone wants to download malicious payload, which you probably can't in a 20 bytes COM file.

Comment: It does not run on 64-bit because it's a 16-bit executable.

Comment: Btw, what does the 97 byte file do ?

Comment: @Overmind: it does nothing, just return. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

For EXE's this small, the most space typically is used for the icon. Typically the icon has various sizes and color schemes contained, which you could get rid of, if you do not care having an "old, rusty" icon, or no icon at all.

There is also some 4k of space used, when you sign the EXE.

As an example for a small EXE, see [never10](https://www.grc.com/never10.htm) by [grc](https://www.grc.com/default.htm). There is a details page which highlights the above points:

https://www.grc.com/never10/details.htm

in the last paragraph:

> A final note: I'm a bit annoyed that “Never10” is as large as it is at
>   85 kbyte. The digital signature increases the application's size by
>   4k, but the high-resolution and high-color icons Microsoft now
>   requires takes up 56k! So without all that annoying overhead, the app
>   would be a respectable 25k.  And, yes, of course I wrote it in
>   assembly language.

*Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with grc in any way.*

Answer (score -1):

The is little need for an executable to be big, except when it contains what I call code spam, code not actually critical to the functionality of the program/exe. This is valid for other files too. Look at a manually written HTML page compared to one written in FrontPage. That's spamcode.

I remember my good old DOS files that were all KB in size and were performing practically any needed task in the OS. One of my .exes (actually .com) was only 20 bytes in size.

Just think of it this way: just as in some situations a large majority of the files contained in a Windows OS can be removed and still the OS can function perfectly, it's the same with the .exe files: large parts of the code is either useless, or has different than relevant-to-objective purpose or are intentionally added (see below).

The peak of this aberration is the code added nowdays in the .exe files of some games that use advanced copy protection, which can make the files as large as dozens of MB. The actually code needed to run the game is practically under 10% of the full code.

A file size of 72 KB as in your example can be pretty sufficient to do practically anything to a windows OS.

To apply this to your programming, as in make very small .exes, keep things simple. Don't add unnecessary code just for the looks of it or by thinking you will use that part of the program/code at a point.